# How do I make an EditText that can accept a list of string, such as that in Gmail or Inbox when adding recipients?

Tags: android, android-edittext

The EditText that I am referring to is that which we can add multiple string values, and can also delete them by backspacing or clicking on it, where a popup will appear.

This is an example of what I mean:

[image: Example of what the OP means]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has generally been referred to as a "chips" UI. It is not built into the Android SDK, but there are [third-party libraries that support it](http://android-arsenal.com/search?q=chips), such as:

- [Chips EditText Library](https://github.com/kpbird/chips-edittext-library)
- [ChipsLibrary](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/ChipsLibrary)